# How do I load geonames.org dataset in mysql

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I am having an issue loading the geonomes data set. Heres my process:

first i create my database **GEONAMES**

then i create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `geoname` (
`geonameid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`asciiname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`alternatenames` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
`latitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
`longitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
`fclass` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`fcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc2` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`admin1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`admin2` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
`admin3` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`admin4` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`population` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`elevation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`gtopo30` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`timezone` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`moddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`geonameid`),
KEY `name` (`name`),
KEY `asciiname` (`asciiname`),
KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
KEY `fclass` (`fclass`),
KEY `fcode` (`fcode`),
KEY `country` (`country`),
KEY `cc2` (`cc2`),
KEY `admin1` (`admin1`),
KEY `population` (`population`),
KEY `elevation` (`elevation`),
KEY `timezone` (`timezone`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

next is where my problem is, I try to load the data an get:

Last error message

Invalid utf8 character string: ''Afikanisitani,'Apekanikana,A Phu Han (Afghanistan),A Phú Hãn '

heres my query for loading the data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'allCountries.txt'
INTO TABLE geoname
CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'
(geonameid, name, asciiname, alternatenames, latitude, longitude, fclass,       fcode, country, cc2, admin1, admin2, admin3, admin4, population, elevation, gtopo30, timezone, moddate);
```

I'm running my queries in sequel pro command line.

Comment: Assuming your data is UTF8, and given that your table is properly set up for UTF8, the problem is most likely in your client (sequel pro). Is it set up to handle utf8, or is it defaulting to Latin or ASCII or UTF16 or something else oddball?

Comment: @JNevill - I have the same issue. I don't use Sequel Pro, I run the MySQL command in Ubuntu's terminal, which has always worked until today. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting [the same error on MySQL 5.7.13](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/145080/98972) - which was strange, since import of the `allCountries.txt` file seemed to work fine in MySQL 5.6

Not sure [what exactly changed between MySQL 5.6 and 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html) but it has something to do with the default `character_set` and `collation` in 5.7

Based on [this Q&A](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,642879,642879) I updated the default character set to `utf8mb4` which then enabled me to load the `allCountries.txt` file without problems

Login to mysql in terminal with `mysql -u root -p` and run the following query:
`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';`

The default MySQL 5.7.13 response looked like:

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value             |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8              |
| character_set_connection | utf8              |
| character_set_database   | latin1            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary            |
| character_set_results    | utf8              |
| character_set_server     | latin1            |
| character_set_system     | utf8              |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

(Working on OS X) I then needed to add a `my.cnf` file to `/etc/my.cnf`
- you can copy it :
`sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf`
- assign `my.cnf` to `_mysql` or it won't be able to read it (common problem if a `my.cnf` file exists but is either owned by root or has too permissive permissions)
`sudo chown _mysql /etc/my.cnf`
- update the config file to include the following (in the relevant sections - just add them if they're not there)

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

- restart mysql (following commands are for OS X):

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

- run the same `SHOW VARIABLE` command in mysql and the results are

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8               |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

...now the `allCountries.txt` file load should work properly.